# Prove that the maximal eigenvalue is less than $1$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a series of column vectors: $ x_{i} =(1,0,0,\dots,c_{i},0,0,\dots,0)\in\mathbb{R}^{N+1} $ where $ c_{i}\neq 0 $ and $ c_{i} $ is on the $ (i+1) $th coordinate of vector $ x_{i} $, $ i=1,2,...,N $. Specially, define $ x_{0} =(1,0,0,...,0)\in\mathbb{R}^{N+1} $. Define the matrix

$$ V := \sum_{i=0}^{N}x_{i}x_{i}^{\top} $$

I want to verify whether

$$ \lambda_{\max} \left( V^{-1} x_{i} x_{i}^{\top} \right) \leq 1 \, \quad\forall i=0,1,\dots,N $$

where $ \lambda_{\max}(\cdot) $ means the maximal eigenvalue of a given matrix.

For the $2$-dimensional case, it can be verified that the eigenvalues are either 0 or $ \pm 1 $. I tried some 3-dimensional cases numerically and found the eigenvalues are also either 0 or $ \pm 1 $.

Comment: Same uppercase for matrices and integers is confusing.

Comment: **Hint:** the nonzero eigenvalue of a rank-1 matrix is its trace.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes, I see. But here maybe I need further consider that whehter the matrix $ A_{i} $ as defined by Jean Marie is eigenvalue decomposable. If $ A_{i} $ is only singular value decomposable, knowing that the kernel is in $ N $ dimensional will still give that there are zero $ N $ singular values?

Comment: What is the rank of $A B$ if $B$ is rank-$1$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: matrix

$$A_i:=V^{-1}x_{i}x_{i}^{\top}$$

is such that $A_i u=0$ for all vectors $u$ orthogonal to $x_i \ne 0$ (a hyperplane).

Therefore, the kernel of $A_i$ in $N$ dimensional.

As a consequence all eigenvalues of $A_i$ are $0$ but one.

Then it remains to show that this eigenvalue is less than $1$.

Comment: Sorry, it is still hard for me to understand this hint. It seems that the hint does not use any information on the definition of $ x_{i} $. Btw, the $ n-1 $ is based on the implicit fact that $x_{i} $ is of dimension $ n $, right?

Comment: It is true that the fact that your $x_i$ have their specific form is not used. The only thing uses is that they aren't $0$. The $n-1$ is the dimension of a hyperplane, yes, in $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Comment: I can understand that the kernel of $ A_{i} $ is $ N $ dimensional. But how to get that the eigenvalues of $ A_{i} $ are N zeros but one? The proof of the non-zero eigenvalue should use the information in $ x_{i} $, right?

Comment: First of all: I hadn't paid attention that the ambient space is $\mathbb{R^{N+1}}$. You have understood that $n=N+1$.  Then: the fact that the kernel is N-dimensional gives you a N-dimensional basis $(u_1,... u_N)$ of the kernel, and all these are such that $A_iu_k=0 \ \iff \ A_iu_k=0u_k$, a fact that means that every $u_k$ is associated with a zero eigenvalue. Therefore eigenvalue zero has multiplicity $N$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Having known that there must exist $N$ zero eigenvalues is very helpful. I can use trace to get some information on the only one non-zero eigenvalue. Btw, given that $A_{i}$ may not be symmetric, is it possible to show that $A_{i}$ always has a eigenvalue decomposition?

Comment: $A_i$ is indeed diagonalizable. You know that the criteria for being diagonalizable is that the dimension of every eigenspace is equal to the order of multiplicity of the associated eigenvalue : this is true for eigenvalue $0$ (dimension $N$ = order of multiplicity $N$). Therefore, as it remains only one dimension for the nonzero eigenvalue, the criteria is completely fulfilled.